# Why does my Python program get UnicodeDecodeError in IntelliJ but is OK from the command line?

Tags: python, json, encoding, intellij-idea

I have a simple program that loads a .json file which contains a funny character. The program (see below) runs fine in Terminal but gets this error in IntelliJ:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position
>   2: ordinal not in range(128)

The crucial code is:

```
with open(jsonFileName) as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)
```

if I replace the open with:

```
with open(jsonFileName, encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Then it works in both IntelliJ and Terminal. I'm still new to Python and the IntelliJ plugin, and I don't understand why they're different. I thought `sys.path` might be different, but the output makes me think that's not the cause. Could someone please explain? Thanks!

**Versions:**

- OS: Mac OS X 10.7.4 (also tested on 10.6.8)
- Python 3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50)   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3.2
- IntelliJ: 11.1.3 Ultimate

**Files (2):**

**1. unicode-error-demo.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
from pprint import pprint as pp
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) is not 2:
        print(sys.argv[0], "takes one arg: a .json file")
        return

    jsonFileName = sys.argv[1]
    print("sys.path:")
    pp(sys.path)
    print("processing", jsonFileName)

#    with open(jsonFileName) as f:           # OK in Terminal, but BUG in IntelliJ: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
    with open(jsonFileName, encoding='utf-8') as f:     # OK in both
        jsonData = json.load(f)
        pp(jsonData)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**2. encode-temp.json**

```
["™"]
```

Comment: Sounds like an environment thing. Check your locale in the terminal (command `locale`) and see what you get. Probably, IntelliJ is not picking that up and uses some default setting, while Python apparently does use the Terminal environment settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON `.load()` function expects Unicode data, not raw bytes. Python automatically tries to decode the byte string to a Unicode string for you using a default codec (in your case ASCII), and fails. By opening the file with the `UTF-8` codec, Python makes an explicit conversion for you. See the [`open()` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#open), which states:

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent.

The encoding that would be used is determined as follows:

- Try [`os.device_encoding()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#os.device_encoding) to see if there is a terminal encoding.
- Use [`locale.getpreferredencoding()` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding), which depends on the environment you run your code in. The `do_setlocale` of that function is set to `False`.
- Use `'ASCII'` as a default if both methods have returned `None`.

This is all done in C, but it's python equivalent would be:

```
if encoding is None:
    encoding = os.device_encoding()
if encoding is None:
    encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
if encoding is None:
    encoding = 'ASCII'
```

So when you run your program in a terminal, `os.deviceencoding()` returns `'UTF-8'`, but when running under IntelliJ there is no terminal, and if no locale is set either, python uses `'ASCII'`.

The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/unicode.html) tells you all about the difference between unicode strings and bytestrings, as well as encodings. Another *essential* article on the subject is Joel Spolsky's [Absolute Minimum Unicode knowledge article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Martijn: Thank you. Before posting I spent a good bit of time researching Unicode (new to me), but I wrote my question to ask more about the two different environments. I also found the comment about the encoding being platform dependent, but I'm running both environments on the same platform... Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @MatthewCornell: I updated my answer; I checked [the sourcecode](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2b79b4848f44/Modules/_io/textio.c#l869) in the end, as this wasn't clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x has strings and unicode strings. The basic strings are encoded with ASCII. ASCII uses only 7 bits/char, which allow to encode 128 characters, while modern UTF-8 uses up to 4 bytes/char. UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII (so that any ASCII-encoded string is a valid UTF-8 string), but not the other way round.

Apparently, your file name contains non-ASCII characters. And python by default wants to read it in as simple ASCII-encoded string, spots a non-ASCII character (its first bit is not 0 as it's 0xe2) and says, 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128).

Has nothing to do with python, but still my favourite tutorial about encodings:

http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/~mikosmul/computing/articles/linux-unicode.html