# Python's JSON library decoder

Tags: python, json

I have two machines - one is having Windows OS and the other one has Linux. I have installed Python on both of them. In file `/Lib/json/__init__.py` there is `loads` method which has code as

```
_default_decoder = JSONDecoder(encoding=None, object_hook=None,
                               object_pairs_hook=None)

return _default_decoder.decode(s)
```

where s is a `str` or `unicode` instance containing a JSON document.

On my Windows machine, I get output where all texts are `unicode` objects but on my Linux machine I rather get `str` objects. I dont know why this is happening. I want them to be `unicode` objects on both machines. Please help.

I have written following code on python shells of both the machine:

```
>>> import json
>>> from json import *
>>> default_decoder = JSONDecoder(encoding=None, object_hook=None,object_pairs_hook=None)
>>> default_decoder.decode(json.dumps({'aaa':'bbb'}))
```

On Windows machine I get:

```
{u'aaa': u'bbb'}
```

whereas on Linux it is:

```
{'aaa': 'bbb'}
```

Comment: Are your machines running different versions of Python? In particular, is the Windows box on Python 2 and the Linux box on Python 3?

Comment: @user2357112 sys. version prints this :

1. Windows - '2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'

2. Linux - '2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 28 2012, 10:55:56) \n[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]'

Comment: I don't see the code you've shown in the online source code of the 2.6 `json` module: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3edf679917ba/Lib/json/__init__.py That might be a difference between 2.6.6 and the final version of the 2.6 branch.

Comment: The [2.6 `json` docs](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/json.html) say you should be getting unicode objects. Can you show an interpreter transcript where you get `str` instead of `unicode`?

Comment: The source code for `/Lib/json/__init__.py` in Python 2.6.6 is [different](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3edf679917ba/Lib/json/__init__.py) that what you have in your question. You might want to run a diff of the file from each system.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for the replies. Please let me know how do I get interpreter transcript?

Comment: Start up the interpreter, do something that demonstrates the problem, then copy-paste the session into the question and code-format it. (You may need to do a bit of looking to figure out how to copy-paste things out of a terminal.)

Comment: @martineau: Yes, the organization of that code is different. First line given here is defined globally for that file and in loads function there is first if condition which has the second line given here.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the actual built-in JSON module, and not some 3rd-party code?

Comment: If you can't install/count-on the same version of Python on both systems, you may have to do some version checking in your own code to handle the different results you're getting to work around the issue.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, I am using in-built JSON module on both machines. I checked entire code, it is same on both machines. Does it have anything to do with encoding settings?

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/a/12409282/66349

Comment: @PeterGibson: I have gone through this post and I am trying that code to check if my problem is related to the one given there but there is no default_encoding attribute/method in my os module.

Comment: os.default_encoding is python 3.x only I believe

Comment: @PeterGibson: Thanks. Please let me know what do I use in Python 2.x to check this?

Comment: Not sure, have you tried locale.getpreferredencoding() on the two machines?

Comment: @PeterGibson: Yes, on Windows it is 'cp1252' whereas on Linux its 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'

Comment: Maybe you could use `sys.setdefaultencoding()` as shown at the beginning of this [config.py](http://microblog-tuner.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/config.py) script I found.